# 3D-plotting sine integral (PSTRICKS)

Tags: pstricks, 3d, asymptote

I'd like to build up a 3D-Plot (based on `pst-solides3d`), where the function looks like

`x=u`, `y=v` and `z=\int_0^x \frac{\sin\left(\pi t \right)}{\pi t} - \frac{1}{3} \mathrm{d}t+\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sin\left(\pi \frac{x}{y}`.

I do not know, how to define this function - esp. the sine integral - within the `\defFunction` argument. Is the a `Si` function?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Bye the way - wouldn't it be great to be able to enter LaTeX-Math-Code directly here - maybe inside of \( \) or so?

Comment: You could always take a screen shot.

Comment: Indeed - but this is not that way easy or elegant as it would be to simply insert $a^2$ or \(a^2\). Further I think most of us here are also able to read Math-TeX code directly.

Comment: We had LaTeX math rendering on in the beginning, [but requested to have it turned off](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181/can-we-turn-off-math-tex-please): This is a site about _TeX_, not math.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the package `pst-func` has a PostScript macro Si which expects a value on the stack and returns the integral. For more information see the documentation of `pst-func`. Here is only an idea of how it can be done. Don't know how to handle your values, because PostScript needs degrees for the sin function which can be done internally with `DegtoRad`:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d,pst-func}

\begin{document}
\psset{Decran=50,viewpoint=10 20 40 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-4)(6,4)
\defFunction{func}(u,v)
  {u}
  {v}
  {u tx@FuncDict begin Si end u 3 div sub u v Div RadtoDeg sin Pi dup mul div add }  
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,base=-1 1 -1 1,function=func,
         ngrid=40 40,hue=0 1]
\end{pspicture}


$x=u$, $y=v$ and 
$z=\int_0^x \frac{\sin\left(\pi t \right)}{\pi t} - 
\frac{1}{3} \mathrm{d}t+\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sin\left(\pi \frac{x}{y}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Herbert, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Now - this results in a new question for me: I tried your example compiling with `xelatex` - but it went wront.
I thaugh with xelatex pstrick should compile fine, or?

Comment: @Bastian: yes, I had no problem with current TeXLive 2010

Comment: Hmmm, you are right - this problem only arises on MikTeX. It is time for me to remove this installation... ;-)
Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

The `Asymptote` is capable of calculations of the integral of `f` from `a` to `b` using adaptive Simpson integration. However, when configured with the GNU Scientific Library (`GSL`), it includes `Si(x) = int(sin(t)/t, t=0..x)` function as well. `plot-si.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Si}{Si}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
z&=\int_0^x \frac{\sin\left(\pi t \right)}{\pi t} - 
\frac{1}{3} \mathrm{d}t+\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sin\left(\pi \frac{x}{y}\right)
=\frac{\Si(\pi x)}{\pi}-\frac{x}3 +\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sin\left(\pi \frac{x}{y}\right)
\end{align}

\begin{asy}
size(200);
size3(200,200,50,IgnoreAspect);
import gsl;
import graph3;
import palette;
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(3,5,4),up=(0,0,1),target=(0,0,0),zoom=0.9);
real f(pair p){return Si(pi*p.x)/pi-1/3*p.x+1/pi^2*sin(pi*p.x/p.y);}
real Arg(triple v) {return f((v.x,v.y));}
real ep=1e-7;
surface s=surface(f, (-1+ep,-1+ep),(1,1),nx=200);
s.colors(palette(s.map(Arg),Wheel()));
draw(s,render(merge=true));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

run `latexmk -f pdf plot-si.tex`.

Comment: I get error when running _latexmk -f pdf plot-si.tex_. So, I try to load it with _txs:///asy-pdf-chain_ in TeXstudio but I get **error: out of memory**, **runscript.tlu:902: command failed with exit code 1: asy plot-si-1.asy**, **Process exited with error(s)**. What should I do to compile it perfectly?

Comment: @chishimutoji: Try it step-by-step:
After step 1: `pdflatex plot-si.tex` : 
the file `plot-si-1.asy` must show up.
Run step 2: `asy plot-si-1.asy` , 
at this step a pdf image `plot-si-1+0_0.pdf`
must be created (may take some time, so be patient)
to be included into the final document on the next step.
And final step - run `pdflatex plot-si.tex` again
and get `plot-si.pdf`. I just checked and got
(1 page, 3300786 bytes) file,
but on the other system the size may be slightly different.

Comment: With step 2: asy plot-si-1.asy , I get **error: out ... asy plot-si-1.asy. :-((. Note: I compile the different files normally. With this file, I don't get output. :-( . I use Asymptote 2.44

Comment: Haiz, I just compile it normally. The reason is ** nx=200 **, it is changed to ** nx=90 **. :-)).

Comment: @chishimutoji: Try to upgrade to the current Asymptote version 2.47?